# indoor grilling

Tags: grilling

I own a great grill pan but the only successful thing I grill on it is thinly pounded chicken cutlets. Does anyone know if I can grill a steak (skirt steak)?

**What general technique can I use on my grill pan to broaden my indoor grilling success?**

Comment: Have you grilled other things unsuccessfully?  Or are you just starting out and wondering what to try next?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your pan.  I have a cast iron grill pan that I get smokin' hot and can grill anything, including skirt steak.

If you have a non-stick grill pan (has T-Fal ™ or Teflon ™) then you shouldn't get it hot enough to do the deed, as you'll wreck the finish.

Basically it just comes down to temperature...if you can get it hot enough you can grill on it.

As for general technique, for thick steaks, I heat the oven to 500 degrees and pre-heat the pan.  I fire up the top of the stove.  I use oven mitts that are designed for high temperatures.  I put the pre-heated pan on the top of the stove and put an oiled and seasoned steak on it.  Two minutes.  Flip.  Two minutes.  Back in the oven (still on the pan) for 5 minutes.  Out on a plate, covered with foil, rest for 5 minutes.

For a thin steak like skirt or flank, you can skip the oven part, although you'll still want to crank the heat.  Cut on the bias.

Comment: This sear-roasting technique works great, though I do it with a regular cast-iron pan for more searing area. I find that I don't usually do so much flipping on the stovetop. For a really thick steak (1.5 inches or so), I do 4 minutes on the first side, flip and bang it into the hot oven. About 6-8 minutes later (I often use a probe thermometer to know when it's ready) it's done and ready to rest.

Comment: what oil do you prefer for this application?

Comment: Can I do this technique with my Teflon grill pan?

Comment: I just use vegetable oil.  It's more about the non-stick than any flavor it might bring.  Any oil that doesn't taste burnt at high temps should work though.

Comment: As for the teflon question, no, you really shouldn't.  The temperature is too high...it has the potential to wreck your pan and Teflon at a high enough temperature breaks down and puts out gases that aren't good for sensitive animals (canary in the coal mine).  Cast iron is your best bet.